# Explainig How this MACRO works ?? [printing VAR name in c++]

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor, variable-names

I'm using this MACRO for debugging in C++ .
Printing the variable name and value.
Can anyone explain its working ?

```
#define watch(x) cout << (#x) << " is " << (x) << endl;
int t = 90;
watch(t);
```

// output is 
 
 `t is 90`

Comment: Run the code through the preprocessor to see how the macro is expanded.

Comment: I also recommend e.g. [this reference about the `#` and `##` macro operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators).

Answer (score 3):

**"stringizing"** operator (**#**) converts macro parameters to string literals without expanding the parameter definition. It is used only with macros that take arguments.